# Match until the next line starts

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I'm using simple HTML dom to get the source of a web page. Then I'm using dom->innerhtml to get the text. I want to match a line that says `var api_response = {...};` however I am having trouble with it continuing to go until the end of the document.

My current regex is `/var api\_response.+\}\;/`

Any ideas?

Comment: Make the repetition non greedy (`.+` -> `.+?`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a regex like this:

```
 /var api_response = \{[^}]+\};/ig
```

or

```
/var api_response\s*=\s*\{[^}]+\};/ig
```